# ehcache diskStore is not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache

my directory of ehcache is not been created whe I set the property  . I am using ehcache-core 2.6.9 and hibernate-ehcache 4.0.1.Final

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="/tmp/ehcacheApp1" />

    <defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="1800" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="80"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="blockiscsi" maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="5" timeToLiveSeconds="10">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="5" eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="120">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000" eternal="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

**update:** I also tried this: `<diskStore path="user.dir/ehcache" />`

I received this log:

```
17:53:31.232 [main] WARN  net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager - diskStorePath '/tmp/ehcache' is already used by an existing CacheManager either in the same VM or in a different process.
The diskStore path for this CacheManager will be set to /tmp/ehcache/ehcache_auto_created1431805507138728176diskstore.
To avoid this warning consider using the CacheManager factory methods to create a singleton CacheManager or specifying a separate ehcache configuration (ehcache.xml) for each CacheManager instance.
```

Comment: have a read [here](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.jp/2014/07/how-hibernate-second-level-cache-works.html)

Comment: yes. it is very good explanation. On my machine it works well. But when I deploy the app to other machine, with the same SO, it hasnt been created. I also have other app at the same machine. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `SingletonEhCacheProvider` setting this

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheP‌​rovider</property>
```